# Change Dynamic Inline CSS Attributes With jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, dynamic-css

I'm attempting to alter the `min-width` and `width` values for a div with class of `.upb_row_bg` . This div has dynamically generated widths. Resizing the browser window will cause these values to change.

Any idea why this jQuery, being loaded via an `add_action` to `wp_footer`, isn't working? Don't know if it matter, but this is an element for Visual Composer that I'm attempting to alter.

```
<div class="upb_row_bg" data-bg-override="9" style="min-width: 1368px; left: -81px; width: 1368px;"></div>

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('div.upb_row_bg').css({"min-width" : "-=40" , "width" : "-=40"});
});
```

Comment: Not working or the other dynamic css code overwrites it? Put a console log and check what is happening.

Comment: You are setting the values to "-=40". What is that supposed to mean?

Comment: Tushar - Because the inline CSS is being dynamically generated through jQuery, based on window size. _____
BasvanStein - No errors in console log. The default CSS code is still in place, so I'm assuming it is overriding whatever modifications I'm trying to make. _____


Chet - I'm trying to reduce the values of min-width and width by 40 pixels of their current value.

Comment: The div I'm trying to alter is full width. I'm trying to add right and left borders to this element. Which is why I'm trying to resize the width to accommodate for the borders.

Comment: @optimus203 - Did you try to get the current value and then subtract from it? Something like this: `minWidth: $('div.upb_row_bg').css('min-width').replace('px', '') -40 + 'px',`.

Comment: @DavidDomain - tried your snippet but no luck.

Comment: @optimus203 - Seems to be working just fine [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/t6bh1k76/)

Comment: @DavidDomain - yup, that works too. But looks like the default styles are overriding what I'm trying to insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original code actually works fine; you can see it here in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rvnfdonz/3/). There is likely something else going on with the website.

The [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method **can** use use relative values as you've pointed out so thats not the issue.

I've edited your code in my examples to make it slightly easier to follow.

```js
$('button').click(function(){
 $('.upb_row_bg').css({"min-width" : "-=40" , "width" : "-=40"});
});
```

```css
.upb_row_bg {
    height: 20px;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>shrink</button>
<div class="upb_row_bg" data-bg-override="9" style="min-width: 100px; width: 100px;"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Quoid. Good idea but no luck.

Comment: @optimus203 have you looked at the fiddle, it is working; the inline code hasn't got jQuery loaded, so its not working there, will edit

Comment: @optimus203 edited the fiddle and the code inside answer (to include jQuery) - click the button to see the `element` shrink in size

Comment: Yup - that is working. But on the site in question looks like the default values are overriding this jQuery revision. Anyway to give this precedence over any other code that may be modifying this inline style?

Comment: actually using relative values, like your [original code](http://jsfiddle.net/rvnfdonz/3/) works fine...

Comment: @optimus203 it's probably Visual Composer (but I'm guessing), would have to see the live site to tell

Comment: The link to dev environment is new.socceropolis.com . You'll see the blue full width area, which is what I'm trying to resolve. On page load you should see the screen flash with element we're trying to alter. But then the default values kick in for that section.

Comment: @optimus203 - what I *think* is going on, is that you have a `function()` that is running on `$( window ).resize()` - so on resize it is adjusting the properties, at the same time you are attempting to *re-adjust* those properties with a *new* `function`. It likely has to do with your function firing order; [see this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h4kjvxsq/).

Comment: It *does* look like the first `script` to be load is your `custom.js` and *then* the other `script`s - I'd try altering your `wp enqueue script` function(s)

Comment: Thanks for the help Quoid. Appreciate it.